# Prove that a side of a triangle is greater than its semiperimeter.

Tags: geometry

This is one of the question in my text book and I dont think I understood this correctly. If we think of a triangle whose all sides are 5 cm. Then, the semiperimeter of this triangle would be 7.5 cm which is greater than a side 5 cm. Since the side is less than the semiperimeter, either I understood the question wrong or the question has mistake. Any comment?

Comment: Any side of a triangle is less than the semiperimeter. Proving that would be a pretty reasonable textbook question, in fact.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Are you saying that the theorem is false??

Comment: Yeah. I mean, you just provided a counter-example, therefore it's false.

Comment: Any side in any triangle would provide a counter-example just as well, because it's not just false: it's always false. :)

Comment: This is a terrifically well known [inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Oh thanks.. I assumed that the text book would be a proof question like this is always true and require some complicated proof. Thank you!

Comment: The correct statement, about each side being less than the semi-perimeter, must be what the authors intended. That does require a proof, but it's not too complicated, I think. :)

Comment: Do you know the fact that the sum of two sides in a triangle is always greater than the third side? Your question is equivalent to this fact which can be found in any geometry texts.

Comment: If you know the basic inequality among the sides of a triangle, that the sum of two sides in a triangle is always greater than the third side, you can prove the fact by adding the third side and then dividing by two to the inequality. You can also see that if $a>s$, then one term in Herons formula would go into imaginary numbers, which is is not allowed [but rule out the possibility that $b$ or $c > s$].

Answer (score 0):

Given a triangle with side A. 
Draw side B from one vertex of A. 
Draw side C from the other vertex of A.

If B+C were less than the length of A, then sides B and C would not meet. 
If side B+C are equal to A then the no triangle would be possible ie no enclosed space.

So B+C > A The side of a triangle (A) is less than the sum of the other 2 sides (B+C). 
A+(B+C)>A+A  Adding A to both sides does not change the inequality

(A+B+C)/2 > 2*A/2 Dividing by 2 on both sides does not change the inequality.

The semiperimeter > A   Definition of semiperimeter and algebraic simplification. 
The semiperimeter of a triangle is greater than the length of an arbitrarily chosen side A.

Note if draw line segments equal to B and C above line A, you should notice that the semiperimeter is equal to side A...plus half of (B+C)-A. 
This makes the semiperimeter an average between a selected side....and the sum of the other 2 sides.

Keselev Geometry Plainemetry page 41 question 89 states

Prove theorems: A side of a triangle is GREATER than its semiperimeter. 
This is an ERROR in the textbook. One side of a triangle is ALWAYS less than its semiperimeter. Please change the word Greater to LESS for this question.